# Why is my gif pixelated in firefox and not in google chrome browser?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a gif as logo in my navbar, in google chrome the gif looks fine but in firefox and internet explorer it is getting pixelated.

Here below the result left chrome right firefox:

[image]

How can I fix this I allready tried is this:

`Image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast` or this `image-rendering: optimizequality;`

But none of them results in a sharp gif

Here is the html with css:

```
<img src="/img/dasbot-logo-wit.gif" alt="" class="logo-img">

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

How is this possible and how can I fix this?

Here is the gif link:
https://gph.is/2HYzaqT

Comment: The pixelated is another version. Perhaps that?

Comment: @AjAX. another version of what?

Comment: The pictures you show are different. The **b**.

Comment: it is a gif which animates both the same gif but that b rotates

Comment: Can you link us the GIF image?

Comment: Ah got it. I vote to @ExillustX.

Comment: For me it looks on all 3 `pixelated`. Exactly same.

Comment: For me it looks pixelated in Chrome: https://i.imgur.com/bXXyv0f.png

Comment: My chrome version is: 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit). If you are wondering...

Comment: I think what @AjAX. suspects is that you're using 2 different gifs, one pixelated, the other smooth. Is that possible?

Comment: I found the answer here: https://wpza.net/wordpress-logo-appearing-pixelated-in-chrome/ — it mentions using `-webkit-transform`.

Answer (score 0):

For all of us, this logo appears to be pixelated around the edges of the words. To fix this, you should download some sort of application, (Coreldraw is my recommendation, just use the trial), then run a quick trace of each frame in the animation. A quick trace just traces the outside of the item and makes it look not pixelated. It also has other functions (laser cutting), but that doesn't matter right now.

Once you have your gif traced, you should re-upload it back onto giphy. This isn't a coding solution as it is a problem with your gif.